# Modal window gets closed when using aura component "forceChatter:publisher" - how can we avoid this?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chatter

We are using an aura component which gets called using a quick action button on an object like account. Besides from other parts in the newly opened modal window, we also want to include Chatter. Unfortunately when the user clicks the "Share" button, the complete modal window closes.

Is there any way to publish the chatter message but don't close the modal window? The intention is, that the user looking at a modal window, can collaborate with other users, receive some feedback, and then continue his / her work in the currently open modal window.

I've minimized the code to show an example (see GIF below).

*MyTestComponent.cmp*

```
<aura:component description="MyTestComponent" implements="force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="public"/>
   <!-- The documentation says, that this is one of the events we could capture -->
   <aura:handler event="forceChatter:postCreated" action="{!c.chatterPosted}" />
   <forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

*MyTestComponentController.js*

```
({
    chatterPosted: function (component, event, helper) {

         // maybe some logic before...
         // event.preventDefault(); // <-- does not work
         // event.stopPropagation(); // <-- does also not work
        
        // how to prevent the modal window from being closed?
    }
});
```

[image: Example using the component above on a custom quick action on account]

Is there any hint on that? How could we avoid, that the modal window closes immediately?

Documentation:

- [Communication with event (SF developer guide)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_intro.htm)
- [Component Reference Publisher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:publisher/documentation)
- [Component Reference Post Created event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:postCreated/documentation)